An unspecified error occurred when tring to connect Github v2 using AWS codepipeline
I am tring to create AWS Codepipeline and select the source as Github (version 2). Connection was successfull but unable to select the connection name shows warning as follow. when tring using version 1 it works and shows available repos. what is the reason for this and how to solve this?
I selected pipeline type as Queued (Pipeline type V2 required)

what is displayed in the Service Health Dashboard?

It shows no recent issues

For those of your confused by the answer given, here's how it works:

Go to the developer tools area in the aws console. This is the same place where CodePipeline, CodeBuild, and CodeDeploy reside.

Click on Settings > Connections in the menu on the left to get the page where you can create connections to repos like github.

Create a new Github connection. It will give you the option of connecting to github as a "bot" or as a github user (see pic below). So you click on the Install a new app button to connect as a bot. I'm not really sure what that means but when I use that option, I don't get the error above when I use this connection for my pipeline.


All of this seems kind of hokey to me. I don't really get what aws is doing here or why connecting as a github user doesn't work but connecting as "bot" does. But I guess if it works it works right? ¯\(ツ)/¯


The same problem happened to me. I made a connection creating an "App installation" insead of the user.
Create connection dialog in AWS Developer Tools

I have already create a connection

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
